# Clipping Mask Ignores Opacity of Elements

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I want to create a grid array of objects. And I want them to clip with the clipping mask. At the same time, all the objects in the grid should have different opacity.

Example in the [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/dVPLbsIwEPyVVS4Jj4YUVZUa2gOiFeJAQW0vFXAwiQGLYEeOgUaIf+86DuRB64udmfGuZ3dzsjjZUcu3PrdUBRurbQUi1N8HImHFomggIiHhBexlRIKt3QOAOddkwGQQ0WQoxT5GntMjZGen0TMCSUK2T5B6yIEkJgHja0Ry6g7uc4rsxJ6ryWpggqKk6yEFWTYjYZxTafh+MibJNk86JWrjGtw5mSsmvA9PXtsAVyM+2JKGdg7HImGKCe7DgdGjG1CuqETurC3c5HMZT6hU/aU4UMe417o5X2GBHP3EH3yS18PtuW4IwVarkT/vqk+NPv1LnxZ6vYqK/2/7si72zd6ukoXnWd6FJj64eWlOG65oWqCLWpByPYUkfE3tehoisZp+ZUpqEqFjq9QHz+1CC8baEMYKxc5pYGrPfazqO53JtD8YfX3DaPg++Xh7LeisYdkBmzfn5aTuxTDWrdTlXk1V7u1N5xvXUdRt2CFCw9u5r1i9HVcdpHTVDSIWxzTEEEruaTZI+PctJSXbWDCuEsufLc6/).

At line 23, I set a random opacity, but when applying the mask this information will be ignored and filled with the mask color. Is it bug of the PaperJS or I'm doing it wrong?

[Image: before/after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOxGP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mask in a masking group should be the first item and not the last.
Here is the corrected [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).
This is the corrected line:

```
var maskedGroup = new Group(innerCircleAsMask, circlesGroup);
```